# How to format table values in vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

If I have an object with `BigDecimal` property, I want to display it in a `Table` with a specific formatting: 2 fractions, and a "+" or "-" sign according to the amount.

Eg: `+10.50`, `-3.20`

How can this be achieved in a vaadin table? There is a method `table.setConverter(..)`, but this would actually force to convert between eg a `BigDecimal.class` and a `String.class`. What I'm more after is just a view formatter that just displays the object data differently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Override` the protected method [`Table.formatPropertValue()`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.2.0/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html#formatPropertyValue%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20com.vaadin.data.Property%29):

```
public class My_table
    extends Table
{
    @Override
    protected String formatPropertyValue(final Object      a_row_id,
                                         final Object      a_col_id,
                                         final Property<?> a_property)

    {
        if (a_property.getType() == BigDecimal.class
            && null != a_property.getValue())
        {
            return "formatted-value";
        }

        return super.formatPropertyValue(a_row_id, a_col_id, a_property);
    }
}
```

See *Book of Vaadin* section [5.16.6. Formatting Table Columns](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html).

Comment: Ok that's great so far. But: what if I only want to display the "+" and "-" signum signs for a specific column, and all other `BigDecimal` colums should not show these signs?

Comment: @membersound, use the `a_col_id` to determine the column the value belongs to.

Answer (score 9):

While using `Table.formatPropertValue()` for formatting table columns is a viable option, I strongly discourage from using this method when working with Vaadin 7. `formatPropertValue()` is the old Vaadin 6 way of formatting Table values. This method is still available in Vaadin 7 for downward compatibility. Using this method is problematic in several ways:

- It is not typesafe. Since you only get a `Property<?>` as a parameter you first have to check for the concrete type of the property value.
- You have to inherit from Table only to adapt the formatting of one or more columns. Class inheritance is definitely the wrong approach for adapting a class's behavior for one particular use case. If you have more than one such cases, you'll end up implementing a bunch of Table subclasses which later can't be easily interchanged.
- You hard-wire conversion code (BigDecimal to String) to the concrete implementation of some UI component. That's bad for re-use. What if you need that conversion in some other place, say when you display a BigDecimal on a Label? You'd have to duplicate this code or somehow extract it into a separate class or method.

The last point is exactly what Vaadin 7 does for you: keep conversion logic separate from some concrete UI component. This is what the `com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter` interface is for. So, the OP was quite right in his/her first assumption: `Table.setConverter()` is the way to go with Vaadin 7. Converters are typesafe and allow for separation of concerns.

The objection that the Converter which can be set with `Table.setConverter()` only converts from BigDecimal to String is not justified in this case. `Table.formatPropertValue()` doesn't do anything different - it also converts to String. But this is obvious, a Table doesn't display anything other than String data in its columns. In fact, the default behaviour of Table is to call the `toString()` method on `Property` value types that it can't convert on its own.

For using Converters, see [section 9.2.3 of the Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/datamodel.properties.html#datamodel.properties.converter).

Comment: I think what the OP wanted to say is that using a `Converter` implies that you also need to implement conversion in the other direction to satisfy the interface.

Comment: Maybe. In any case, it's save to use a `Converter` only in one direction, as long as it isn't used on field components. Either of `Converter`'s conversion methods could throw an UnsupportedOperationException. Sometimes it is not even possible to convert the presentation data to the model data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own table class extending `Table` and override `formatPropertyValue(Object rowId, Object colId, Property<?> property)`.

See section 5.15.6 in the [book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/components.table.html)